# How to make a theme fully compatible with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, woocommerce, integration

Woocommerce [docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/) state that in order to make the theme compatible, this function should be called `woocommerce_content();` But I have seen many themes that don't use that but still get full support of WC templating system.

To be precise, for example when making a product search, I need woocommerce to load this `templates\loop\result-count.php` instead of just applying filters and displaying the theme's `search.php`.

To see what I mean, let's try a search on both a [Pro theme](http://demo2.woothemes.com/forthecause/?s=logo&post_type=product), and  a [free theme](http://demo2.woothemes.com/mystile/?s=cap&post_type=product); the pro theme is fully integrated with woocommerce and makes use of templates from woocommerce plugin directory, whereas, the free theme is just using the normal `search.php`. The same thing applys to using the default Twenty Fourteen theme; it uses `search.php` too for products.

I have looked inside the code of the pro theme and there isn't `woocommerce_content();` so I'm wondering how they do that!

I checked the WC docs but they are poor and don't explain very well how to fully do the integration.. Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some unorthodox ways on debugging, I finally find out why Woocommerce is not loading in the example given above (when searching), the pro theme strips off categories from the search query!

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'woo_exclude_categories_homepage' );
```

This makes woocommerce validate when checking against `woocommerce_products_will_display()` that goes further and calls `is_product_taxonomy()` that also goes deeper and calls `is_tax( get_object_taxonomies( 'product' ) )`!

The documentation mentions nothing of the above and without deep knowledge of wordpress, it is not easy to figure out on the first page!

Hope it helps/saves time to someone else..

**Update**

Strange enough; It turns out that executing `$query->parse_query();` on the function call of `pre_get_posts` solves the ussie of the search!

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpf_exclude_categories_homepage');
function wpf_exclude_categories_homepage($query) {

    $query->parse_query();  

    return $query;
}
```